# Inode number shows same in soft link

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

When I create soft link for directory,after that I check inode number its show me same when I check in following pattern,why it show me same?

```
mkdir /focus
ln -s /focus /tmp/focus1
ls -lid /focus/ -> eg.1122
ls -lid /tmp/focus1/ -> 1122
Its same but I check like as follow it show differ
ls -lid /tmp/focus1
what is difference between /tmp/focus1/ and /tmp/focus1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include a trailing `/`, `ls` is listing the contents of the directory. When you do not, it is providing information about the symbolic link itself.

Comment: Hi William can you ex plane me using example or in simple words,I didn't  understand

Comment: `/fmp/focus1` is a symbolic link to the directory `/focus`, which is empty.  Your implementation of `ls` is simply behaving differently based on the presence of `/` at the end of the argument.  It would help if you showed the actual output you are getting.